# komodo edit 7.1 doesn't recognize html5 tags in php mode

Tags: debugging, komodoedit, code-editor

The title is pretty explicative! In php mode komodo edit assume html4 and raise errors when html5 tags like article, time, section are used.

This could be pretty troublesome since it could cover php errors.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe solution found:

Preferences -> Languages -> HTML -> Default HTML Document Type -> HTML5