# Komodo Edit 8 doesn't recognize Django tags for HTML5 pages

Tags: debugging, django-templates, komodoedit, code-editor

I am using Komodo Edit 8 for a Django project. HTML5 pages do not recognize django template tags for syntax highlighting or code intelligence. However, HTML pages do accurately recognize these tags. Is there a setting that can be adjusted? Can I just make all HTML5 pages be recognized as only an HTML page?

It appears to me that .html files that are snippets are recognized as HTML (4) and .html files that contain the `<html>` tag are recognized as HTML5.

I [found this StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253843/komodo-edit-7-1-doesntt-recognize-html5-tags-in-php-mode), but the answer does not correct my problem

My Komodo build is:
    Komodo Edit, version 8.0.2, build 12590, platform linux-x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was a total noob question. The answer is simple. To solve, switch the file type from "HTML5" to "Django" using the selector on the status bar at the bottom of the application.