# "HTML: Error: <nav> is not recognized!" In Komodo Edit

Tags: html, nav, komodo, komodoedit

I am working on an index.html file and inside my head and body tag, I have a nav element.  However, in Komodo Edit, version 10.1.1, build 17414, platform linux-x86_64., It red-underlines the nav element and gives me the following erorr message:

> HTML: Error: `<nav>` is not recognized!

This is what my code looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body><div class="sidebar"></div><nav class="main menu">

            <ul class = button-container>
              <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-font" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
              </li>      

              ...

              <li>
                <i class="fa fa-picture-o" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="export button-container">
                <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
                </li>  
            </ul>

        </nav>
          <nav class="menu font" style="display: none;">
                  <p>Font</p>
        </nav>

        ...

        <nav class="menu picture" style="display: none">
          <p>Pictures</p>

        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: can you provide more details

Comment: Jishnu V S: Do you want more code?

Comment: yes, because how can we find the error only this one

Comment: Sounds like Komodo is simply not up-to-date on the current state of HTML5. // Is this just a warning, or does it stop you from saving the document …?

Comment: CBroe: It's jsut a warning and I can still save the document.  I'll post more code right now.  I'm also at the latest version of Komodo Edit from the Manjaro Linux Repo.

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253843/komodo-edit-7-1-doesntt-recognize-html5-tags-in-php-mode

Comment: James Donnelly:  Thanks, I just tried that but it's been set to HTML5 already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komodo has 2 "Languages" that cover HTML, one is called "HTML" and one is called "HTML5". HTML5 covers the nav element, HTML does not. You need to change your language selection to HTML5.

The language selection is done from the right side of the statusbar, it should currently say "HTML".

Comment: Thank you.  I had set it to HTML5 in the preferences already, but it didn't fix it until I did the language selection from the ride side of the status bar.

Comment: You might have opened the file before you changed your language preference in the preferences window. Komodo remembers the language of a file the next time you open it, and changing the default language in Preferences doesnt change it for files that are already opened.

Answer (score 0):

Can this Work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body><div class="sidebar"></div><nav class="main menu">

            <ul class = button-container>
              <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-font" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
              </li>      

              ...

              <li>
                <i class="fa fa-picture-o" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="export button-container">
                <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" style="font-size:6em;"></i>
                </li>  
            </ul>

        </nav>
          <nav class="menu font" style="display: none;">
                  <p>Font</p>
        </nav>

        ...

        <nav class="menu picture" style="display: none">
          <p>Pictures</p>

        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

this Might not work but guess Ill try